# Performing algebra with newtypes based on integers Haskell

Tags: haskell, algebra, newtype

I'm having some trouble with performing simple addition, subtraction -- any kind of algebra really with Haskells newtype.

My definition is (show included so I can print them to console):

```
newtype Money = Money Integer deriving Show
```

What I'm trying to do is basically:

```
Money 15 + Money 5 = Money 20
Money 15 - Money 5 = Money 10
Money 15 / Money 5 = Money 3
```

And so on, but I'm getting

```
m = Money 15
n = Money 5
Main>> m-n

ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Num Money
*** Expression : m - n
```

I can't find a clear and consise explanation as to how the inheritance here works. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is no inheritance. every type must implement all of its typeclass instances by itself.

Comment: Will Ness is right, though I'd remark that quite often GHC can _derive_ those instances automatically for you. Just you do need to ask it... and for `Num`, deriving is actually not possible at all currently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well Haskell can not add up two `Money`s, since you never specified how to do that. In order to add up two `a`s, the `a`s should implement the `Num` typeclass. In fact `newtype`s are frequently used to specify *different* type instances, for example [`Sum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum) and [`Product`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:Product) are used to define two different monoids.

You thus need to make it an instance of [**`Num`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num), so you have to define an instance like:

```
instance Num Money where
    Money a + Money b = Money (a+b)
    Money a - Money b = Money (a-b)
    Money a * Money b = Money (a*b)
    abs (Money a) = Money (abs a)
    signum (Money a) = Money (signum a)
    fromInteger = Money
```

Since [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) is a member of the `Fractional` typeclass, this will give some problems, since your `Money` wraps an `Integer` object.

You can however implement the [`Integral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) typeclass such that it supports `div`. In order to do this, we however need to implement the [`Real`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Real) and [`Enum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Enum) typeclass. The `Real` typeclass requires the type to be implement the [`Ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord), and since the `Ord` typeclass requires the object to be an instance of the [`Eq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) typeclass, we thus end up implementing the `Eq`, `Ord`, `Real` and `Enum` typeclass.

```
instance Eq Money where
    Money x == Money y = x == y

instance Ord Money where
    compare (Money x) (Money y) = compare x y

instance Real Money where
    toRational (Money x) = toRational x

instance Enum Money where
    fromEnum (Money x) = fromEnum x
    toEnum = Money . toEnum

instance Integral Money where
    toInteger (Money x) = x
    quotRem (Money x) (Money y) = (Money q, Money r)
        where (q, r) = quotRem x y
```

## `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`

As [@Alec says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188123/performing-algebra-with-newtypes-based-on-integers-haskell/53188346?noredirect=1#comment93280036_53188346) we can use a GHC extension named [**`-XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving).

The above derivations are quite "boring" here we each time "unwrap" the data constructor(s), perform some actions, and "rewrap" them (well in some cases either unwrapping or rewrapping are not necessary). Especially since a `newtype` actually does not exists at runtime (this is more a way to let Haskell treat the data differently, but the data constructor will be "optimized away"), it makes not much sense.

If we compile with:

```
ghc -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving file.hs
```

we can declare the `Money` type as:

```
newtype Money = Money Integer deriving (Show, Num, Enum, Eq, Ord, Real, Integral)
```

and Haskell will perform the above derivations for us. This is, to the best of my knowledge, a GHC feature, and thus other Haskell compilers do not *per se* (well they can of course have this feature) support this.

Comment: nice much more in depth than my answer :)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`... :)

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a instance of how your money can add together, the clue was in the error `Instance   : Num Money`.

So for addition in Haskell the `Num` type what is needed to add two things together as long you are dealing with numbers so let's make an instance of `Num` on `Money`:

```
newtype Money =
  Money Integer deriving Show

instance Num Money where
  Money a + Money b = Money $ a + b

-- Money 1 + Money 2 == Money 3
```

Notice that it returns `Money`, will let you research how you can get the number out of the type :)