# Making newtype instance of Integral class in haskell

Tags: haskell, newtype

I want to make my newtype instance of Integral class. 
My newtype:

```
newtype NT = NT Integer deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)
```

I want to be able to do `div` with my `newtype NT`:

```
Prelude> (NT 5) `div` (NT 2)
2
```

Since:

```
Prelude> :t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

I should make my `NT` instance of `Integral` class.

This is how is `Integral` class defined:

```
class  (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a  where
    quot, rem        :: a -> a -> a   
    div, mod         :: a -> a -> a
    quotRem, divMod  :: a -> a -> (a,a)
    toInteger        :: a -> Integer
```

and Since I need only `div` I tried:

```
instance Integral NT where
  (NT x) `div` (NT y) =  (NT q)  where (q,r) = divMod x y
```

or can I do this?

```
instance Integral NT where
  div (NT x)  (NT y) =  NT (div x y )
```

but either way I get the error:

```
• No instance for (Real NT)
  arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
• In the instance declaration for ‘Integral NT’
```

Should I make `NT` instance of `Real` class First and how?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53188123/67579

Comment: Yes, a type has to have both `Real` and `Enum` instances before you can declare an instance for `Integral`. That's what `(Real a, Enum a) => Integral a` means in the class definition.

Comment: If you only need `div`, you probably shouldn't declare any instance at all. Just define a custom div-like function and use that.

Comment: In cases like this, there is no need to edit a "solved" note into your question. Instead, leave a comment saying the suggested question solves the problem, so that the rest of us know it is okay to close it as a duplicate. (Also, if someone casts a duplicate vote and it doesn't close the question immediately, an option will show up for you to confirm the duplicate.)